# Laravel: get current route namespace in view (form.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

i am using laravel 5.4 for my project and i just want to get the route namespace or prefix in my blade file. So is it possible to get the route group namespace?

**My Route:**

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'organization','namespace'=>'Organization'], function(){
            Route::get('team/{id}',['as'=>'info.team' , 'uses'=>'ManageTeamController@info']);
});
```

**Blade File:**

```
{{dd(\Request::url())}}
```

i am getting this:

```
"http://ocrm.dev/organization/team/8"
```

so i just need:

```
http://ocrm.dev/organization
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the prefix instead of namespace , because your namespace and prefix seems to same.

```
$request->route()->getPrefix()
```

Comment: and how i can get prefix?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`starts_with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-starts-with) and [`currentRouteName()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#accessing-the-current-route) to check if route name starts from specified namespace string:

```
if (starts_with(Route::currentRouteName(), 'Organization.'))
```

If you want to check URL, use `is()` method:

```
if (request()->is('organization*'))
```

If you want to get route prefix which is `organization`, here's a bit modified solution by @sandeep, but globally available (so you could use in views, controllers, custom classes etc.):

```
request()->route()->getPrefix()
```

So, to get this URL:

```
http://ocrm.dev/organization
```

You could use [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-url) helper. This solution is also globally available:

```
url(request()->route()->getPrefix())
```

Comment: i just need that what is here in route prefix.. i don't know whether its organization or something else

Comment: @RahulSharma I've updated my answer with globally available solution.